# Removing special characters from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I'm new to programming (and R) and I run into a problem when trying to remove some characters from dataframe. I have imported a csv with NAV data from a mutual fund. After importing I'm left with a dataframe (named a) formatted like this. The class of both columns is factor.

```
Date             NAV
="03/08/2017"    ="â‚¬209.0537"
="02/08/2017"    ="â‚¬208.7831"
="01/08/2017"    ="â‚¬208.7373"
etc.
```

I just need the dates and NAV prices without the equals sign, double quotes, â, "comma" and "¬":

```
Date             NAV
03/08/2017       209.0537
02/08/2017       208.7831
01/08/2017       208.7373
```

I tried to use gsub() to as a first step remove the first equals sign and double quotes:

```
b <- gsub(pattern = "^=\"", replacement = "", x = a)
```

This gives me a character vector of length 2, which I don't understand. I also tried to coerce the classes of the columns to "Date" and "Numeric", respectively, but this completely messed up my data.

In the end I want to have an xts with the dates in YYYY-MM-DD format, but I can fix the date formatting and the conversion to xts myself when the other characters are removed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the columns, using `gsub` match characters that are not `-` or `/` or `.` or numbers and replace it with blanks (`""`), assign the result back to the dataset and convert the second column to numeric

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) gsub("[^-0-9/.]+", "", x))
df1[,2] <- as.numeric(df1[,2])
df1
#        Date      NAV
#1 03/08/2017 209.0537
#2 02/08/2017 208.7831
#3 01/08/2017 208.7373
```

If this needs to be converted to `xts`

```
library(xts)
xts(df1[-1], order.by = as.Date(df1$Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
#                NAV
#2017-01-08 208.7373
#2017-02-08 208.7831
#2017-03-08 209.0537
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("=\"01/08/2017\"", 
"=\"02/08/2017\"", "=\"03/08/2017\""), class = "factor"), NAV = structure(c(3L, 
 2L, 1L), .Label = c("=\"â‚¬208.7373\"", "=\"â‚¬208.7831\"",
 "=\"â‚¬209.0537\""
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Date", "NAV"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. The first part solved my problem. The only change I made was the dat format (the source was dd/mm/yyy). Can you explain the part after "data"?

Comment: @Alexander91  DId you meant the `format` part`?  i.e. `%m/%d/%Y`" it suggests month followed by day followed by Year

Comment: Yes, the dates in my file are formatted as %d/%m/%Y.

Answer (score 1):

The `readr`package has a function `parse_number` which exactly does what you require without having to formulate regular expressions:

```
library(readr)    
parse_number("â‚¬209.0537")
```

yields

`209.0537`

as required.